# Issues when merging a C++ project with a Qt project

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl, boost

This project is a MVC using Qt (and OpenGl) in the View part and Boost Graph library in the Controler part.

I have Developed the model and the view part on Eclipse CDT, and it successfully compile and run. The view part is developed under QtCreator, the window compile and run successfuly too.

But when i add the model and the controller files in the Qt project i have some compilation issues.

I'm on Mac OSX Mavericks, Boost 1.55.0, Qt 5.2.1 (lastest version of Qt creator)

Here is the compilation output :

```
MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../../../Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I../IBirdCVGui -I</Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/interface/testsQt/IBirdCVGui/boost_1_55_0/> -I../../../../../Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../../../../Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../../../../Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../../../../Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -F/Users/thomas/Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib -o main.o ../IBirdCVGui/main.cpp
/bin/sh: -I../../../../../Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/Headers: No such   file or directory
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
14:32:02: Le processus "/usr/bin/make" s'est terminé avec le code 2. //ended with code 2
Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet IBirdCVGui (kit : Desktop Qt 5.2.1 clang 64bit) // error in compilation/deployment of project IBirdCVGui
Lors de l'exécution de l'étape "Make" //in "make" execution
14:32:02: Temps écoulé : 00:00.
```

I looked in The file Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/Headers, and the output of my ls is:

```
(Canopy 32bit) rivesaltes:Headers thomas$ ls
5.2.1               QtOpenGL
QGLBuffer           QtOpenGLDepends
QGLColormap         QtOpenGLVersion
QGLContext          qgl.h
QGLFormat           qglbuffer.h
QGLFramebufferObject        qglcolormap.h
QGLFramebufferObjectFormat  qglframebufferobject.h
QGLFunctions            qglfunctions.h
QGLFunctionsPrivate     qglpixelbuffer.h
QGLPixelBuffer          qglshaderprogram.h
QGLShader           qtopenglglobal.h
QGLShaderProgram        qtopenglversion.h
QGLWidget
```

There is like 10 .h files and 10 .cpp files in my project, so if you want to see the code, i can post it but is there something more usefull than just post it here.

So i have several questions:

- Am i missing something big here ?
- Why Qt open Gl is whining when i try to add some "classic" C++ code?
- Is boost graph library potentialy messing with Qt ?
- Is something to know with Qt that i missed in my tutorials?

Comment: the second line of the error output is telling, the include path for the QT headers is faulty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
/bin/sh: -I../../../../../Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/Headers: No such   file or directory
```

typically is showing that there is a line in a `Makefile` that broke in the wrong place (maybe it's a backslash + newline with a space between them). Check the generated Makefiles and you'll probably find your problem.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more, i think i'm not understanding. I can post my makefile if needed, but it is autogenerated by Qt creator. I'm a newbe in MakeFiles, so a little bit more could help. Thanks

Comment: Please, do post your generated Makefile

Comment: Your path to boost is between <> in the line 18 of the generated makefile, indicating that you probably edited your project file, leaving those special characters there. Delete them from the project file and you should be good to go...

Comment: I can't upvote because it's my first post, but seriously, Thank you. :)

Comment: You can choose my answer as the answer to your question!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look to the cause of

> /bin/sh:
>   -I../../../../../Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/Headers:
>   No such file or directory

before asking myself all the other questions. Maybe there is just something wrong with the "../../../../../". If I were you, I'd check the path

> ../../../../../Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/Headers

from the working directory first.

Hope that it helps :)

Comment: My workspace is located here:
~/Documents/workspace/interface/testsQt/build

and Qt is located here:
~/Qt

So i think the path is good. The ../../../../../ is auto generated buy QtCreator i think.